# Bad substitution when using code in .sh file

Tags: bash

This script is to post in my Facebook page with Reddit post. I got error in this line:

```
SUBJECT=$(wget -qO- "${PICTURE::-4}" | perl -l -0777 -ne 'print $1 if /<title.*?>\s*(.*?)(?: - Imgur)?\s*<\/title/si')
```

Comment: What error did you get?

Comment: An error message is a piece of text. This is by design. It is intended to be read.

Comment: Error: Bad substitution

Comment: You are probably using `dash` instead of `bash`; `${PICTURE::-4}` isn't in the POSIX specification for shells.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You appear to be using a non-POSIX feature in a shell that does not support it. (Likely, you are using `dash` instead of `bash`.) Try replacing

```
${PICTURE::-4}
```

with

```
${PICTURE%????}
```